# SVG UTF-16 encoding doesn't work as expected

Tags: xml, firefox, svg, utf-16

I have a file(proprietary format) from a windows system which is UTF-16 encoded.
Now am trying to display it with a svg file. 
I have this header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="2000px" height="2000px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" >
```

The data, for example, is being displayed like this in hexedit:

```
4E 00 41 00                       NA
```

This is working when there are no characters above decimal 127 in value.
For example,
`B0 00` (the degree symbol in UTF-16) doesn't work and I get the error in 
rekong saying "encoding error".
Also, with or without the degree symbol, Firefox gives me encoding error.
I am also replacing BOM with `""`.
Did also try to swap bytes thinking it was endianess problem but this is
the right byte order for the little endian system am using.

What do you think the problem is?

Thanks!

Comment: "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="1980px" height="2715px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" >" That's the header, didn't get displayed above.

Comment: Please provide a full example, so that we may understand your question and reproduce your problem.

Comment: Do you try with a byte order mark at the start? Is there a reason you're not just using UCS2 or UTF8?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox and UTF-16 encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169278/firefox-and-utf-16-encoding)

Comment: Was unable to give full file because the 00 is not displayed as null but as "^@" and I couldn't add any text with that character here. Will try to give a c++ file to generate the file am getting. Also, I have seen the previous question but I also have problems in other browsers with the degree character. Did try with BOM at start of every string. No effect, rekonq still hasproblem with degree character, firefox doesn't display with or wo degree symbol. The reason I want to stick with UTF-16 is that I am getting the strings in UTF-16 and there can be no string with any other encoding.