# Firefox not able to parse pages with encoding UTF-16

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, utf-8, utf-16

I am working on an application which works fine in all browsers except Firefox. In firefox I get html/javascript code directly displayed as code on web page, instead of being rendered properly. It works fine if I change it to UTF-8. The application is an AngularJS SPA.

I am worried about this behaviour of Firefox as the application needs to support all browsers.

Comment: Are you properly declaring the UTF-16 charset used? How exactly?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18231475/476

Comment: ahha...indeed my application requires UTF-8 only but I came across this issue when Visual Studio 2015 in Team Explorer accidently set the encoding to UTF-16 internally somehow, thought in properties it still showed UTF-8. If you click advance-> identify it shows UTF-16, still I don't understand why Chrome and IE handles it but Firefox can't.